# SQLite use year with date functions in where clause and group by

Tags: android, sqlite

I am keeping date time values(Unix timestamps) in a "NUMERIC" format in SQLite table, the value is calculated through Java Date function:

> new Date().getTime();

The values look like proper date/time  when I load these in an Android program, but when I try to experiment with queries through SQLite data browser 2 beta the results are awkward. Numeric values are given below:

> 1391313058888
>   1391313104336
>   1391313175752

When I try to apply date function the SQLite data browser shows following for all three rows:
-1413-03-01 13:07:12
My query is

> SELECT date(trxDateTime, 'unixepoch') from trx_log

I was trying to figure out how to get correct date values in the first place, once I got those then I believe I could figure a way to use it in where clause or group by.
Basically I am trying to show totals sales by year. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Everything at the end in SQLite maps to a String.

Comment: I am thinking maybe I should store date/time in string format instead of numbers and use strftime sort of thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your times are in milliseconds. Just convert them to seconds, and you'll be fine:

```
SELECT date(trxDateTime / 1000, 'unixepoch') from trx_log
```

Comment: Minutes before your answer, I had changed schema to store string in format 'yyyy-mm-dd'. Your solution is really cool. I put together following query to get sums by year:
SELECT strftime('%Y',trxDateTime) as valYear, SUM(trxAmount) from trx_log GROUP BY valYear

Comment: Well, that's up to you. If you wish to keep using Unix timestamps, you can always do `strftime('%Y', date(trxDateTime / 1000, 'unixepoch'))` and get the same results.